# Refresh a View's Results when back button is used

Tags: views, 8

I have a view in Drupal 8 with a few filters all set to remember the last selection. This view uses AJAX.

If you use the filters and navigate away, then hit back, the state of the filters and results are not the most recent selection you made. Refreshing the page, however, updates everything with the last selection you made.

How can I preserve these settings and results without needing a manual refresh?

I believe this is related to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1248332) but it doesn't look like there has been much activity on it. I'm hoping someone might have a recommendation to get "remember selection" working well with AJAX.

Comment: Sounds like something you _might_ be able to do with a JS cookie on your own, but, don't quote me on that.

Comment: This is a general browser issue. When you press back, the page is displayed as it first was. Any interactions and their results via Ajax  are forgotten. Last time I checked this was by design and impossible to get around, the exception being if you convert that part of the site to SPA and use the js history API to manage state instead of traditional requests.